# Ask about how to get react data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, console.log

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { dbService } from "./myFirebase";

function Editor({ userObj }) {
  const [myContent, setMyContent] = useState("");
  const [myContents, setMyContents] = useState([]);
  const getValue = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setMyContent({ ...myContent, [name]: value });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1", myContents);
    dbService.collection("contents").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const communityArray = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      setMyContents(communityArray);
      console.log("2", myContents);
    });
    console.log("3", myContents);
  }, []);
  console.log("4", myContents);

  const addContent = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await dbService.collection("contents").add({
      content: myContent,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
    });
    setMyContent("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="submit" onClick={addContent}>
        {" "}
        input{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Editor;
```

[image]

When data is entered in this way, I coded it to be saved and received in Firebase.

If I print the log, it comes out as an empty array and then the value is entered.
So when I get it, if I say `console.log("10", myContents[0].id);`, it is properly received, but when I refresh it, `TypeError: Cannot read property'id' of undefined appears.`

I think it's because of that empty array, how do I fix it?
Are you using async await for useEffect? I tried, but it was the same, was it wrong?

Comment: How about adding this code `if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) ` before `const communityArray = snapshot.docs.map`

Comment: I tried with the suggested method but I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property'id' of undefined`